# Ajax call makes div flicker when css is added to div

Tags: html, css, ajax

I am refreshing a div with an ajax call that seems to work well if no styling is applied to the div. Once I apply any styling to the div the div flickers when the ajax call is done. So every second the div is flickering.

I have read numerous articles that has said to refresh a hidden div then replace the visible div with the contents from the hidden div, but while digging through that I seen claims that sometimes the Ajax call cannot be completed in time for that to happen? I'm kind of at a loss on what to do for this.

I am relatively new to Ajax, so any hints, tips, tricks and so on will be cool.

**CSS**

```
#Wrapper{
    background-color: silver;
}

#OilTempTag {
    float:left;
}
#OilTempTag section {
    width: 50%; 
    float: left;
}
```

**Main HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../Jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
<!--auto refresh div function-->
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('load.shtm', function (data) {
            $('.compOverview').html(data);
        });
    }, 1000); 
});
</script>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Compressor Overview</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Wrapper">
<center><h1>COMPRESSOR OVERVIEW</h1></center>

<center><div class="compOverview">

</div>

</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page Ajax is calling**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
</head>


<div id="overviewtable">
    <section id="OilTempTag">
        Oil Temperature: 
    </section>
    <section id="OilTempValue">
     <%#TagSSI,Oil_Temp%>
     </section>
        <br>
    <section id="ControllerStateTag">
        Controller State: <%#TagSSI,Controller_State%>
    </section>
        <br>
    <section id="DischargeTempTag">
        Discharge Temperature: <%#TagSSI,Discharge_Temp%>
    </section>
        <br>
    <section id="PlantPressureTag">
        Plant Pressure: <%#TagSSI,Plant_Pressure%>
    </section>    
        <br>
    <section id="TotalHoursTag">
        Total Hours: <%#TagSSI,Total_Hours%>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you have a <head> section in the ajax response, you can just return the div alone

Comment: I'm pretty sure the flickering isn't related to ajax at all. Does this flicker for you? http://jsfiddle.net/zLhdmpyr/

Comment: I think it was the `<head>` tag. Once I took it out of there everything worked as it should.

Comment: @tripleb taking the head out of there solved the issue with the flickering. I don't know why, but it did. The only reason I had it in there was to be able to add that part of code of my css sheet. I just used an alternative method to style it Thanks!

Comment: It's because adding the head also added the stylesheet again which caused a redraw